# Could applying for pass/fail with a grade showing in the transcript affect my chances of entering a PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gpa, administration, covid-19

Because of Covid 19, we are facing multiple dilemmas regarding putting courses on pass\fail option.

As an applied biology MSc student, my GPA is currently 4.10 out of 4. All of my courses are (A+) and (A), this semester I got one (A-) in Molecular biology, and I was going to apply pass/fail on it. It will affect my GPA (from 4.10 down to 4), but our University (J.U.S.T) provides the grade on the transcript even if it was counted  as pass/fail, so that the universities outside my country could evaluate me more easily,
(A-) is not terrible at all and it's actually good. But i didn't want to gamble on the GPA since I've got 4 courses left.

Will considering this one course as pass/fail affect my PhD chances?

Answer (score 4):

The worst that would happen is that people (myself) would wonder why you are gaming the GPA at such a fine level. What are your educational goals? Grades only? How much trouble will you give me in the future if I think you deserve a "less than perfect" mark?

I realize this is a personal and pessimistic view, but I'd suggest you focus your mental efforts elsewhere. For study in the US, the extremely minor difference in the GPA would have exactly zero effect. But don't let it raise questions about your attitude.